# Does Python's Type-Hinting Syntax Provide an "Any" equivalent without importing the Typing Module?

Tags: python, types, type-hinting

Is there a way to express a `Typing.Any` equivalent in standard Pyhon syntax without use of the Typing module?

Example:

`my_list: [str] = ['one', 'two', 'three']` == `my_float: Typing.List[str] = ['one', 'two', 'three']`

Is there an equivalent as such:

`my_generic: ??? = surprise` == `my_generic: Typing.Any = surprise`

Comment: `[str]` is not a valid type hint btw. You want `list[str]` there. It isn't an error, but it doesn't do anything to linters either unless a specific linter has that as a special case.

Comment: "No" and why would you want to?

Comment: Depending on the circumstance, [no type hint at all is equivalent to `Any`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-any-type): "A function parameter without an annotation is assumed to be annotated with Any. If a generic type is used without specifying type parameters, they are assumed to be Any"

Comment: @Carcigenicate It seems there is a curveball there; linters will pick up the type-issue but the interpreter will throw a `TypeError` indicating that the `list` object isn't subscriptable. Looks like typing module or bust.

Comment: You need to update your version of Python to at least 3.9, or put `from __future__ import annotations` in the file for `list[str]` to work. I'm not sure if the `__future__` import is allowed in an interactive session though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Ahh, that's it! I'm using 3.8.x